# AWS route53 wrong dns redirection of www.mysite.fr

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have an issue about my route53 redirection to my site static hosted on S3 behind a cloudFront.

So, untill the end of S3 everything is gonna be right. The CF distribution is opened & accessible from internet.

I have registred domaine name on route53 => mysite.fr
Requested ACM for the CloudFront and plugged 3 alternates domaines names :

```
-www.mysite.fr

-*.mysite.fr

-mysite.fr
```

In The route53,
I have `*.mysite.fr` to CloudFront distribution
& `www.mysite.fr` to CloudFront distribution

My issue is when i'm trying to access to `www.mysite.fr`, my redirected to `grandi.Com` and not my site.
Thereforce when i'm request `test.mysite.fr` , I have the right site.

I'm not understand why my `www.mysite.fr` are not redirected on the CF distribution.

Thank you for the heko

Comment: To add an element. On gandi.net with whois, i have the NS of my route53

Answer (score 0):

Again to add information,

I have an access from one EC2 instance but from my localComputer i have a Connection refused...
But the Cloudformation link is accessible. It's really a probleme between R53 & CF

Comment: Don't post this as an answer, instead edit the original question.